# Allow Comments by Default for Multiple Post Types

Tags: php, functions

I have this working for one post type, but need to do it for three. I tried the "else" statements but I realized I suck at PHP.

```
function my_comments_open( $open, $post_id ) {

$post = get_post( $post_id );

if ( 'contacts' == $post->post_type )
  $open = true;

return $open;

}
```

Comment: You can use [`in_array()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp) - `in_array( $post->post_type, array('contacts', 'post_type', 'post_type') )`.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So I'm taking a shot at where to put this:
`function my_comments_open( $open, $post_id ) {

$post = get_post( $post_id );

if ( in_array( $post->post_type, array('contacts', 'companies', 'properties') )
  $open = true;

return $open;

}`

Does that look correct?

Comment: Yes, it does, except you're missing the closing `)` for the `if` block. Anyway, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function default_comments_on( $data ) 
{
    $myCustomPostType = array("my_custom_post_type_1", "my_custom_post_type_2", "contacts"); /* Custom Post Type Array */

    if (in_array($data['post_type'], $myCustomPostType))
    {
        $data['comment_status'] = 'open';
    } 

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'default_comments_on' );
```

**Add this code in functions.php**